# Ansible module to get all service information of windows

Tags: ansible

Is there any ansible module which can give the list of all services in windows. Win_Service requires a name parameter to given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so there is any in-build module. May be you can try with a wild card if name accepts *

If not then you can run a simple power shell command via ansible for that

Comment: Wild card * did not work. So I think powershell is the only option for now.